# Handle request over TCP connection using django

Tags: django, web-services

I'm developing a server using django. There are numbers of devices that connect to this server and send request periodically. How can I handle these requests properly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look into django signals to setup webhooks to listen for certain things to call other things etc... signals was built to keep your app in sync with changes being made throughout.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/